# wsl --mount mounts same block device to all distros?

Tags: mount, wsl2

The documentation for the `wsl --mount` subcommand says “Attach and mount a physical disk in all WSL2 distributions…” but that’s ridiculous, given that more than 1 distribution may be running at the same time. Multiple VMs trying to access the data on the same block device using ext4 as read/write would be a complete train wreck.

Am I missing something about this?

Comment: Maybe it just means it will *work* in all distros not that it *actually* mounts?

Comment: On a related note, I see that /mnt/wsl is mounted as tmpfs, yet files saved there in 1 distro are available in another. Normally, tmpfs is in the memory of the system in which it is running (maybe with some swap) so how is that possible? Files stored there seem to remain until `wsl --shutdown` or until the Windows host is shut down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation for the wsl --mount subcommand says “Attach and mount a physical disk in all WSL2 distributions…” but that’s ridiculous, given that more than 1 distribution may be running at the same time. Multiple VMs trying to access the data on the same block device using ext4 as read/write would be a complete train wreck.

It's not multiple VMs; all WSL2 instances run as containers inside a single VM and share the same running kernel (provided by Microsoft as part of the WSL2 "system distro").

---

(It is *not exactly* the case that only WSL1 uses containers while WSL2 uses VMs. Rather, the difference to be emphasized is that WSL1 uses containers *directly on top of the NT kernel* which emulates Linux ABI, whereas WSL2 uses containers on top of a real, Hyper-V virtualized Linux kernel.)

Comment: "The primary differences between WSL 1 and WSL 2 are the use of an actual Linux kernel inside a managed VM, support for full system call compatibility, and performance across the Linux and Windows operating systems." AND "WSL 2 is running as a hyper-v virtual machine." -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions

Comment: Yes, it's a real Linux kernel running in a VM, but it's still only one instance of that kernel across all running "distros". (The comparison is because WSL 1 _wasn't_ Hyper-V based at all, and it did not run anything close to actual Linux either.)

Comment: Aha! That's what I was not getting.
```
$ uname -r
5.15.90.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```
Same output in all distros. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and if you ran this on WSL1 it would instead show Windows NT acting as a "Linux-compatible" kernel (much like Wine pretends to be Windows). That's the major difference.

Comment: (Though an identical "uname -r" in itself does not imply a single kernel instance; WSL2 *could* just as well have been one VM per distro while still booting the Microsoft Linux kernel across all distros. Their kernel has a bunch of patches to better integrate with the WSL environment, so the stock Ubuntu kernel couldn't really be used.)

Comment: I did think of the fact that identical kernel version does not mean same instance, but it does show me that it's not the kernel from the distro and supports the assertion that a single kernel instance is being used.